# SFINAE and variadic template classes

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm creating a `class C` that inherits from variable amount of classes. List of those classes is defined, for example: `A,B`. In function of `class C` I need to call functions from all base classes but objects can be `C<A,B>` , `C<A>`or `C<B>` so if I will call functions of `class A` in `C<B>` I will get an error. Here is example of the classes and how I've tried to solve problem:

```
    class A
    {
        int a;
    public:
        virtual void set_a(const int &value)
        {
            a = value;
        }
    protected:
        virtual int get_a()
        {
            return this->a;
        }
    };
    class B
    {
        int b;
    public:
        virtual void set_b(const int &value)
        {
            b = value;
        }
    protected:
        virtual int get_b()
        {
            return this->b;
        }
    };
    template<class ...T>
    struct Has_A
    {
        template<class U = C<T...>>
        static constexpr bool value = std::is_base_of < A, U > ::value;
    };

    template<class ...T>
    class C :
         virtual public T...
    {
    public:
    #define HAS_A Has_A<T...>::value

        void f()
        {
    #if HAS_A<>
            auto a = this->get_a();
    #endif
        auto b = this->get_b();
        cout << HAS_A<>;
    }
};
```

When I call `f()` of object `C<A,B>` it skips the call `get_a()` but output is `true`.

Initially, I wrote this

```
template<class U = C<T...>>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<A, U>::value, int>::type get_a()
{
    return -1;
}
template<class U = C<T...>>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A,U>::value, int>::type get_a()
{
    return A::get_a();
}
```

But I don't want to rewrite this for all functions of `A` and `B`. Let's assume that `A` has 10 more functions.

Is there any beautiful solution?

P.S Sorry for my English. I never used SFINAE before. 
Basically I have bunch of genes and I want to write convenient wrap for them where one can configure genes that he wants organism to have.

Comment: I don't think your code will compile: class template `C` is not defined when it's used in class template `Has_A`.

Comment: What do you need this for? This looks really strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use C++17, the bipll's solution (`if constexpr ()`) is (IMHO) the better one.

Otherwise, C++11 or C++14, I'm not sure it's a good idea but I propose the following solution because it seems to me funny (and a little perverted).

First of all, instead of `Has_A` I propose a more generic `isTypeInList`

```
template <typename...>
struct isTypeInList;

template <typename X>
struct isTypeInList<X> : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename X, typename ... Ts>
struct isTypeInList<X, X, Ts...> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <typename X, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct isTypeInList<X, T0, Ts...> : public isTypeInList<X, Ts...>
 { };
```

I also propose the use of the simple `indexSequence`

```
template <std::size_t...>
struct indexSequence
 { };
```

that is inspired to `std::index_sequence` that (unfortunately) is available only starting from C++14.

So, inside `C<T...>`, you can define the template `using`

```
  template <typename X>
  using list = typename std::conditional<isTypeInList<X, Ts...>{},
                                         indexSequence<0u>,
                                         indexSequence<>>::type;
```

so that `list<A>` is `indexSequence<0>` if `A` is part of the `T...` variadic list, `indexSequence<>` (empty sequence) otherwise.

Now you can write `f()` that simply call an helper function `f_helper()` that receive as many `indexSequence`s as many types you need to check.

By example: if you need to know if `A` and `B` are part of the `T...` variadic list, you have to write `f()` as follows

```
  void f ()
   { f_helper(list<A>{}, list<B>{}); }
```

Now `f_helper()` can be a `private` function and can be

```
  template <std::size_t ... As, std::size_t ... Bs>
  void f_helper (indexSequence<As...> const &,
                 indexSequence<Bs...> const &)
   {
     using unused = int[];

     int a { -1 };
     int b { -1 };

     (void)unused { 0, ((void)As, a = this->get_a())... };
     (void)unused { 0, ((void)Bs, b = this->get_b())... };

     // do something with a and b
   }
```

The idea is that `As...` is `0` if `A` is in `T...` or empty list otherwise.

So

```
int a { -1 };
```

initialize `a` with the value of your fake `get_a()`.

With

```
(void)unused { 0, ((void)As, a = this->get_a())... };
```

is executed `a = this->get_a()`, only one time, iff (if and only if) `A` is in the `T...` variadic list.

The funny part of this solution is that `a = this->get_a()` isn't a problem when `A` isn't in the variadic list. Isn't there if `As...` is an empty list.

The following is a C++11 full working example (where I've renamed in `Ts...` the `T...` variadic sequence for `C`)

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A
 {
   private:
      int a;

   public:
      virtual void set_a (int const & value)
       { a = value; }

   protected:
      virtual int get_a ()
       { std::cout << "get_a()!" << std::endl; return this->a; }
 };

class B
 {
   private:
      int b;

   public:
      virtual void set_b (int const & value)
       { b = value; }

   protected:
      virtual int get_b ()
       { std::cout << "get_b()!" << std::endl; return this->b; }
 };

template <typename...>
struct isTypeInList;

template <typename X>
struct isTypeInList<X> : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename X, typename ... Ts>
struct isTypeInList<X, X, Ts...> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <typename X, typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct isTypeInList<X, T0, Ts...> : public isTypeInList<X, Ts...>
 { };

template <std::size_t...>
struct indexSequence
 { };

template <typename ... Ts>
class C : virtual public Ts...
 {
   private:
      template <typename X>
      using list = typename std::conditional<isTypeInList<X, Ts...>{},
                                             indexSequence<0u>,
                                             indexSequence<>>::type;

      template <std::size_t ... As, std::size_t ... Bs>
      void f_helper (indexSequence<As...> const &,
                     indexSequence<Bs...> const &)
       {
         using unused = int[];

         int a { -1 };
         int b { -1 };

         (void)unused { 0, ((void)As, a = this->get_a())... };
         (void)unused { 0, ((void)Bs, b = this->get_b())... };

         // do something with a and b
       }

   public:
      void f ()
       { f_helper(list<A>{}, list<B>{}); }
 };


int main()
 {
   C<>     c0;
   C<A>    ca;
   C<B>    cb;
   C<A, B> cab;

   std::cout << "--- c0.f()" << std::endl;
   c0.f();
   std::cout << "--- ca.f()" << std::endl;
   ca.f();
   std::cout << "--- cb.f()" << std::endl;
   cb.f();
   std::cout << "--- cab.f()" << std::endl;
   cab.f();
 }
```

Comment: a classical TL:DR; I'm afraid.

Answer (score 5):

In current standard, this is trivial:

```
void f() {
    if constexpr(Has_A<T...>::value) {
        auto a = get_a();
    }
    auto b = get_b();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with function-member-pointer.

`call_if_base` calls the given function-pointer only if `baseT` is the base of `T`. However all function-results are ignored and it requires at least one parameter.

```
template <class baseT, class T, typename funcT, class ...Args>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<baseT, T>::value, void>::type call_if_base(T& obj, funcT func, Args... args) {
    (dynamic_cast<baseT&>(obj).*func)(args...);
}

template <class baseT, class T, typename funcT, class ...Args>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<baseT, T>::value, void>::type call_if_base(T& obj, funcT func, Args... args) {

}   

template<class ...T>
class C :
     virtual public T...
{
public:
    void set(const int &value) {
        call_if_base<A, C>(*this, &A::set_a, 0);
        call_if_base<B, C>(*this, &B::set_b, 5);
    }
};
```

or as member-functions

```
template<class ...T>
class C :
     virtual public T...
{       
public:
    void set(const int &value) {
        call_if_base<A>(&A::set_a, 0);
        call_if_base<B>(&B::set_b, 5);
    }
protected:
    template <class baseT, typename funcT, class ...Args>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<baseT, C>::value, void>::type call_if_base(funcT func, Args... args) {
        (dynamic_cast<baseT&>(*this).*func)(args...);
    }

    template <class baseT, typename funcT, class ...Args>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<baseT, C>::value, void>::type call_if_base(funcT func, Args... args) {

    } 
};
```